# How to use BLToolkit generate T4 models for MySql?

Tags: mysql, t4, bltoolkit

[image]

the image is the project folder and files.

this is what I doing:

1.Create a Console Project.
2.in the Nuget Console input "install-package BLToolkit"
3.in the Nuget Console input "install-package MySql.Data"
4.Copy the Templates folder to root directory.
5.add a new .tt file to root,and write:

```
    <#@ template language="C#"  debug="true"#>
<#@ output extension=".generated.cs"   #>
<#@ include file="Templates\BLToolkit.ttinclude" #>
<#@ include file="Templates\MySql.ttinclude"    #>
<#
    ConnectionString = "Database=test;Data Source=127.0.0.1;User Id=root;Password=123;pooling=false;CharSet=utf8;port=3306";

    Namespace = "ConsoleDemo";
    DataContextName = "DataModel";

    GenerateModel();
#>
```

but if I build the project,or exec the .tt,more wrong:
[image]
It's says "Can't find the class or namespace "GeneratedTextTransformation".

I'm tring day and day,and on mssql it's OK,but on mysql,too wrong.

any body know why? help me!

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I' facing similar problem in the past, and I ends up using [SSMA for MySQL](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28764).

The idea is generating an identical SQL Server database, and use that to generate your DAL. Requires more work, but at least it works :)